# Enable Chrome Extensions in Google Chrome App webview

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, webview, google-chrome-app, google-chrome-webview

I'm building a Google Apps [Chrome App](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/webstore/apps-create.html) (not extension but ***app***) with gmail, calendar, etc.

I would like to run extensions from regular chrome in my app. For example, rapportive is a fantastic extension for gmail. But it seems that extensions do not run on pages hosted in a `webview`.

Does anyone have an idea of how enable extensions in chrome apps?

Comment: There is a [permission request event](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview#event-permissionrequest).  Its `plugin` variant might also work for extensions; if not, you can request that they add support for extensions by filing a bug report.  Webviews are supposed to support all normal browser features, but often only on an opt-in basis.

Answer (score 1):

Extensions in Chrome Apps aren't available by design. A webview is meant to facilitate displaying web-based content that *you* control, in which case you'd have the ability to alter that content at the server, rather than relying on an extension to do so.

Incidentally, you should take note of the applicable [terms of service](https://developers.google.com/chrome/web-store/program_policies), which won't let you publish the app you've described in the Chrome Web Store: "Do not post an app where the primary functionality is to link to a website not owned by the developer."

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I believe webview is meant for more than just your content. Google's example talks about an RSS reader where you show a read pane for the content of a blog post. I believe that extensions would still be useful here. As for my app, it's not linking to other sites (hosted app), it is basically window management around Google Apps.

Comment: The difference is the term "primary." That would exclude your case (designed for specific sites you don't control) but allow the RSS reader case (designed for content in general). It's a subtle distinction, but the idea is to separate wrapper apps from apps that provide significant value on their own. I don't want you to put your time into an app that the Store will decline to list, so I hope you understand where that TOS is coming from.

Comment: There are certainly valid use cases for this.  Don't make negative assumptions about the context in an answer, especially if your response lacks an actual answer.