# chrome app using extension and plugin

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, webview, google-chrome-app

I'm developing a Chrome App with a webview. The original web (which I call with a webview) needs to use an extension and a plugin.

Is there any way to allow my App to use them through the webview?

I know about the chrome.runtime.sendMessage for communications, but all the work is already done between the main page, the extension and the plugin. I would to do the App to work only as a "launcher". Is this possible or my approach is a mess?

I read something about google's thoughts about to allow apps to "enable" or to "use" extensions but didn't found any detailed information.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, extensions will not run under a Chrome App by design (even by accessing them through a webview). There was a similar question posted previously, detailing the issues: [Enable Chrome Extensions in Google Chrome App webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21561978/enable-chrome-extensions-in-google-chrome-app-webview)

Comment: In such cases, it's better to flag questions as duplicates.